# How are objects loaded in php/apache across http requests?

Tags: php, apache

I have a simple php script that acts as a controller on an apache server that looks like this:

do_something.php

```
class Processor {
  // fields
  ...
  // methods
  ...
}
$param = $_GET['param'];
$resp = new Processor()->process($param);
echo json_encode($resp);
```

I want to instantiate the `Processor` class only once. If I place the class in a separate file, say, `processor.php`, and make it a singleton, and in my `do_something.php` include the `processor.php` and get an instance, something like below. **will apache initialise the singleton and process file only once? or every time the request is made? (i.e. will this guarantee that the same Processor instance is being across requests?)**

processor.php

```
class Processor {
  // fields
  ...
  // methods
  ...
}
// singleton impl goes here
```

do_something.php

```
include 'processor.php';
$param = $_GET['param'];
$resp = Singleton->getInstance()->process($param);
echo json_encode($resp);
```

Comment: Your sample singleton code is bit off though. By default everything has a lifetime of 1 request in PHP. Thats why a singleton pattern is a bit silly in PHP, in my opinion. So yes the singleton will be initiated once every request. U could memcache the instance to preserve the singleton and make the singleton for every user the same though

Comment: Data does not persist through requests by default. If you really want to do that (you probably don't need to nor want to) use serialization. Also some in-memory user cache extensions allow you to pass objects around.

Comment: ok. thanks for responding.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4251861/object-persistence-in-php/4251914#4251914