# How to repeatedly build a list each time the same script is called in php

Tags: php, arrays

I would like to be able to build a list so that when my php script is called
I should see one object added to the array when I call a second time I should see
two objects then three e.t.c.

My url is as follows:

http://localhost/router.php/forwardtoAdduser/avalue/lookingglass/email@hotmail.com

and my router php file is as follows:

```
function forwardtoadduser ($urlParams) {

    $adminclass = new Admin();


    $user = new User();

    $user -> username = $urlParams[3];
    $user -> password = $urlParams[4];
    $user -> emailaddress = $urlParams[5];



    $adminclass -> adduser($user);


}
```

My admin.php file is as follow:

```
class Admin {

    public $arr = array();

function adduser($user)
  {


    //make a multidimensional array to reference the user id
    //as well as the user data


    $arr = (array)$this;


    array_push($arr, $user);


    //open a connection


    var_dump($arr);

    //var_dump($arr[0] -> username);


  }
```

When I run the php script each time I only see one object to the list. I get:

```
array(2) { ["arr"]=> array(0) { } [0]=> object(User)#2 (3) { ["username"]=> string(6) "avalue" ["password"]=> string(12) "lookingglass" ["emailaddress"]=> string(17) "email@hotmail.com" } }
```

and I should get e.g. if I ran the script twice:

```
array(2) { ["arr"]=> array(0) { } [0]=> object(User)#2 (3) { ["username"]=> string(6) "avalue" ["password"]=> string(12) "lookingglass" ["emailaddress"]=> string(17) "email@hotmail.com" } }
array(2) { ["arr"]=> array(0) { } [0]=> object(User)#2 (3) { ["username"]=> string(6) "avalue" ["password"]=> string(12) "lookingglass" ["emailaddress"]=> string(17) "email@hotmail.com" } }
```

I am trying to call the script with some c# code.

how do I achieve such an outcome?

Comment: You are creating a new instance of `Admin` each time you call `forwardtoadduser` so this will create a new empty array. As PHP is stateless you must use some storage type to preserve data between calls, the easiest way is to use the session, store the array on it and restore it on the `Admin` constructor.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4251861/object-persistence-in-php